# How can I find how many selected rows in a grid are selected on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a table and rows belonging to this table. With getSelection() I can find out which row data I selected but I could not find how many rows I selected and the information of the selected rows using this function. How can I do this in Javascript or ExtJS?  I wrote a code like the one below but the code did not work.

```
var list = [];

for (var i = 1; item.up('Table1').down('#grd2').getSelection()[0].data.length; i++){
    liste.push(item.up('Table1').down('#grd2').getSelection()[i].data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled multiple selection, the number of selected rows can be obtained like:

```
item.up('Table1').down('#grd2').getSelection().length
```

Using ExtJS Array functions you can try this code:

```
var list = [];

Ext.Array.each(item.up('Table1').down('#grd2').getSelection(), function(item) {
  Ext.Array.push(list, item);  
});
```